# Change xeCJK without editing its source code

Tags: expl3, xecjk

In `xeCJK.sty` there is this command:

```
\clist_const:Nn \c__xeCJK_CJK_chars_clist
  {
    "02EA -> "02EB ,
    "2E80 -> "2EFF ,
    "2F00 -> "2FDF ,
    "2FF0 -> "2FFF ,
    "3000 -> "303F ,
    "3040 -> "309F ,
    "30A0 -> "30FF ,
    "3100 -> "312F ,
    "3130 -> "318F ,
    "3190 -> "319F ,
    "31A0 -> "31BF ,
    "31C0 -> "31EF ,
    "31F0 -> "31FF ,
    "3200 -> "32FF ,
    "3300 -> "33FF ,
    "3400 -> "4DBF ,
    "4DC0 -> "4DFF ,
    "4E00 -> "9FFF ,
    "A000 -> "A48F ,
    "A490 -> "A4CF ,
    "AC00 -> "D7AF ,
    "F900 -> "FAFF ,
    "FE10 -> "FE1F ,
    "FE30 -> "FE4F ,
    "FF00 -> "FFEF ,
    "16FE0 -> "16FFF ,
    "17000 -> "187FF ,
    "18800 -> "18AFF ,
    "18B00 -> "18CFF ,
    "18D00 -> "18D7F ,
    "1AFF0 -> "1AFFF ,
    "1B000 -> "1B0FF ,
    "1B100 -> "1B12F ,
    "1B130 -> "1B16F ,
    "1B170 -> "1B2FF ,
    "1F200 -> "1F2FF ,
    "20000 -> "2A6DF ,
    "2A700 -> "2B73F ,
    "2B740 -> "2B81F ,
    "2B820 -> "2CEAF ,
    "2CEB0 -> "2EBEF ,
    "2F800 -> "2FA1F ,
    "30000 -> "3134F
}
```

I would like to change it by deactivating the FF00-FFEF range. When I add a comment sign in the source code of `xeCJK.sty`, like this:

```
\clist_const:Nn \c__xeCJK_CJK_chars_clist
  {
    "02EA -> "02EB ,
    "2E80 -> "2EFF ,
    "2F00 -> "2FDF ,
    "2FF0 -> "2FFF ,
    "3000 -> "303F ,
    "3040 -> "309F ,
    "30A0 -> "30FF ,
    "3100 -> "312F ,
    "3130 -> "318F ,
    "3190 -> "319F ,
    "31A0 -> "31BF ,
    "31C0 -> "31EF ,
    "31F0 -> "31FF ,
    "3200 -> "32FF ,
    "3300 -> "33FF ,
    "3400 -> "4DBF ,
    "4DC0 -> "4DFF ,
    "4E00 -> "9FFF ,
    "A000 -> "A48F ,
    "A490 -> "A4CF ,
    "AC00 -> "D7AF ,
    "F900 -> "FAFF ,
    "FE10 -> "FE1F ,
    "FE30 -> "FE4F ,
%    "FF00 -> "FFEF ,
    "16FE0 -> "16FFF ,
    "17000 -> "187FF ,
    "18800 -> "18AFF ,
    "18B00 -> "18CFF ,
    "18D00 -> "18D7F ,
    "1AFF0 -> "1AFFF ,
    "1B000 -> "1B0FF ,
    "1B100 -> "1B12F ,
    "1B130 -> "1B16F ,
    "1B170 -> "1B2FF ,
    "1F200 -> "1F2FF ,
    "20000 -> "2A6DF ,
    "2A700 -> "2B73F ,
    "2B740 -> "2B81F ,
    "2B820 -> "2CEAF ,
    "2CEB0 -> "2EBEF ,
    "2F800 -> "2FA1F ,
    "30000 -> "3134F
}
```

then I get exactly what I need.

My question: how can I apply this change without editing the source code of `xeCJK.sty`? Because I need this change only for a specific TeX file, not in general. And I would like to use the modified xeCJK also under Overleaf, where I have no access to the core `xeCJK.sty` file.

I have tried adding the modified command into my TeX file, it didn't worked. I have tried writing a `xeCJK-modification.sty` file to be loaded after `xeCJK.sty`, it didn't worked. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: You can create a local copy (under a different name) with the changes you want.

Comment: Try `\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{Default}{"FF00 -> "FFEF}`, which sets/changes characters `"FF00 -> "FFEF` (from class `CJK`) to class `Default`. This command is documented in `texdoc xeCJK`, sec. 3.4 设置 CJK 字符范围.

Comment: Thank you muzimuzhi, it works fine! Can you please convert your comment into an answer so that I can validate it?